# Celery (Django) Rate limiting

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, celery, carrot

I'm using Celery to process multiple data-mining tasks. One of these tasks connects to a remote service which allows a maximum of 10 simultaneous connections **per user** (or in other words, it **CAN** exceed 10 connections globally but it **CANNOT** exceed 10 connections per individual job).

I **THINK** [Token Bucket (rate limiting)](http://celeryproject.org/docs/internals/reference/celery.worker.buckets.html) is what I'm looking for, but I can't seem to find any implementation of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much research I found out that Celery does not explicitly provide a way to limit the number of concurrent instances like this and furthermore, doing so would generally be considered bad practice.

The better solution would be to download concurrently within a single task, and use Redis or Memcached to store and distribute for other tasks to process.

Answer (score 11):

Celery features rate limiting, and contains a generic token bucket implementation.

Set rate limits for tasks:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.rate_limit

Or at runtime:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#rate-limits

The token bucket implementation is in Kombu

Comment: Alas, this doesn't work properly because it's per queue. I came up with a better solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66161773/64911

Answer (score 3):

Although it might be bad practice, you could use a dedicated queue and limit the worker, like:

```
    # ./manage.py celery worker -Q another_queue -c 10
```

Comment: I don't think is bad practice. It's a queue with a different usage and consuming pattern so... to me it makes sense if it's a different queue.