# Rate limit a celery task without blocking other tasks

Tags: python, django, celery

I am trying to limit the rate of one celery task. Here is how I am doing it:

```
from project.celery import app

app.control.rate_limit('task_a', '10/m')
```

It is working well. However, there is a catch. Other tasks that this worker is responsible for are being blocked as well.

Let's say, 100 of `task_a` have been scheduled. As it is rate-limited, it will take 10 minutes to execute all of them. During this time, `task_b` has been scheduled as well. It will not be executed until `task_a` is done.

**Is it possible to not block `task_b`?**

By the looks of it, this is just how it works. I just didn't get that impression after reading [the documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.rate_limit).

Other options include:

- Separate worker and queue only for this task
- Adding an `eta` to the task `task_a` so that all of it are scheduled to run during the night

**What is the best practice in such cases?**

Answer (score 1):

The **easiest** (no coding required) way is separating the task into its **own queue** and running a **dedicated worker** just for this purpose.

There's no shame in that, it is totally fine to have many Celery queues and workers, each dedicated just for a specific type of work. As an added bonus you may get some more control over the execution, you can easily turn workers ON/OFF to pause certain processes if needed, etc.

On the other hand, having lots of specialized workers idle most of the time (waiting for a specific job to be queued) is not particularly **memory-efficient**.

Thus, in case you need to rate limit more tasks and expect the specific workers to be idle most of the time, you may consider increasing the efficiency and implement a [Token Bucket](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/celery-throttling-setting-rate-limit-for-queues-5b5bf16c73ce). With that all your workers can be generic-purpose and you can scale them naturally as your overall load increases, knowing that the work distribution will not be crippled by a single task's rate limit anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This should be part of a task declaration to work on per-task basis. The way you are doing it via `control` probably why it has this side-effect on other tasks

```
@task(rate_limit='10/m')
def task_a():
    ...
```

After more reading

> Note that this is a per worker instance rate limit, and not a global rate limit. To enforce a global rate limit (e.g., for an API with a maximum number of requests per second), you must restrict to a given queue.

You probably will have to do this in separate queue

Comment: Just tested it. Same thing happened

Comment: If you prefer not to be limited to queues, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66161773/64911